# linq query and ado entity framework +visual studio 2010

Tags: ado.net-entity-data-model

I used an ado entity data model and added it to my web application. When I want to debug
with breakpoints, I can't see the data of the query, only a reference to the model.

Comment: please im doing my tesis

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't executed the query by iterating over the results (e.g. using `foreach` or `ToList`) then this is expected.

All that

```
var query = from e in db.SomeTable
             select e;
```

does is set up code that can eventually be executed and produce the results of the query but it doesn't produce the results until you iterate over `query` as above.

Beyond that, you haven't given us much to go on.

Comment: i´ve used foreach e.g that is an example of a method   public List<Permiso> VerPermisosdelUsuario(int idrol)
        {
            List<Permiso> lisrRP = new List<Permiso>();
            var query = from p in contextoBD.Roles
                        where p.IdRoles == idrol
                        select p.Permisos.ToList();
            foreach (var item in query)
            {
                lisrRP = item;
            }



            return lisrRP;

        }

Comment: i´m just doing a web application ,and  naw i´m doing the authentication, ive used a link on the sitemaster, cause i had problems with the default login and i dont like that it implement things on the webconfig.. i dont know so much about that ...if you have a better way please it could be very helpfull

Comment: also i have on the ado entity model a rol,permisions,rolpermission ,users, usersRols tables for the authentication